# 2 Displays on a VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, xubuntu

I have a PC with Windows installed on it. I also installed Virtual Box that opens a virtual machine with Xubuntu OS.I want to be able to use two screens also on the virtual machine. I also configured VirtualBox to have 2 screens.

[image]

However, when I log into the virtual machine, I see that the VM recognizes only one screen.

[image]

My host OS, Windows, of course recognized 2 displays.

What do I have to do so my VM will be able to identify 2 displays?

Comment: Did you install the guest additions?

Answer (score 4):

Is the second monitor disabled? Please check in the status bar to make sure it is enabled.
[image: Enable Display in status bar]

Comment: This was my exact issue! Note: on Virtual Box 6.1 (and probably earlier), if you are in full screen mode, the option to enable the secondary screen will not be visible. You have to be in windowed mode and click the display icon as in the image above.